# How to cluster icons in a time scale upon zooming out in D3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, cluster-analysis

I have a D3 (using D3 version 3.5.2) time scale chart utilizing only the x-axis at this point. The graph plots a series of svg "rect" elements on the x-axis based on an array of dates while it randomizes the data points on the y-axis to prevent clustering issues. The chart also has the ability to zoom and pan.

What I would like to do is upon zooming out of the scale is the following:

Cluster all the icons together so that it shows a new icon when zoomed out based on the "collective overlapping amount of events or data points" for a particular vertical slice of the timeline chart as the user zooms out.

For example, if there are seven data points clustered for the month of May, 2018, then it would show an icon with the number of events for that particular vertical time slice (or the month of May, 2018) showing inside the icon, so in this case the number seven will appear in the clustered icon box. Zooming into May, 2018 would cause the "clustered icon" to disappear and show the actual seven individual "rect" elements displayed across the time scale (so Tue, 23th, Thursday, 25th, etc...).

The tricky part here would be to grab the actual number of elements for the zoomed out vertical slice of a particular date and render the clustered icon as the user zooms out, and do the opposite when the user zooms in (hide the clustered icon and render individual icons across the timeline).

**Here's my current code:**

```js
//D3 Timescale demo

const width = 1200,
    height = 500,
    parsedDate = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse;

const changedDates = [
    '1988-01-01', '1988-01-02', '1988-01-03',
    '1988-01-04', '1988-01-05', '1988-01-06',
    '1988-01-07', '1989-01-08', '1989-01-09',
    '1995-01-10', '1995-01-11', '1998-01-12',
    '1998-01-13', '1998-01-14', '2002-01-15',
    '2002-01-16', '2002-01-17', '2004-01-18',
    '2004-01-19', '2004-01-20', '2004-01-21',
    '2004-01-22', '2007-01-23', '2007-01-24',
    '2007-01-25', '2007-01-26', '2007-01-27',
    '2008-01-28', '2008-01-29', '2008-01-30',
    '2008-01-31', '2008-02-01', '2010-02-02',
    '2010-02-03', '2010-02-04', '2012-02-05',
    '2012-02-06', '2012-02-07', '2012-02-08',
    '2014-02-09', '2014-02-10', '2014-02-11',
    '2017-02-12', '2017-02-13', '2017-02-14',
    '2018-02-15', '2018-02-16', '2018-02-17',
    '2018-02-18', '2018-02-19', '2018-02-20'
].map(d => parsedDate(d));

const svg = d3.select('#timescale')
        .append('svg')
            .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
            .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
            .classed('svg-content', true);
        // .attr('width', width)
        // .attr('height', height);

const clipPath = svg.append('defs')
    .append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'clip')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', width - 110)
    .attr('height', height);

const xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(Date.parse(d3.min(changedDates, d => d))), new Date(Date.parse(d3.max(changedDates, d => d)))])
    .range([10, width - 110]);

const yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([200, 0])
    .range([0, height - 29]);

const xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickSize(1)
    .orient('bottom');

const yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .tickSize(1)
    .tickValues([0, 100, 200])
    .orient('right');

const zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on('zoom', function () {
        svg.select('g.xaxis').call(xAxis).selectAll('text').style('font-size', '10px');
        updateEvents();
    }).x(xScale);

// Draw base area to interact on
const rect = svg.append('rect')
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('y', 0)
                .attr('width', width - 100)
                .attr('height', height)
                .attr('opacity', 0)
                .call(zoom);

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'xaxis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 10 + ',' + 480 + ')')
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .style('font-size', '10px');

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'yaxis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 1100 + ',' + 10 + ')')
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .style('font-size', '10px');

const renderEvents = dates => {
    const events = svg.selectAll('rect').data(dates);

    events.enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'item')
        .attr('x', d => xScale(d))
        .attr('y', () => Math.random() * 100)
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('height', 10)
        .attr('transform', (d, i)  => (i === changedDates.length - 1) ? 'translate(' + 0 + ',' + 362 + ')' : 'translate(' + 10 + ',' + 362 + ')')
        .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
        .style('fill', 'blue');

    events.exit()
        .remove();
}

const updateEvents = () =>  {
    // The console logs here are to try and figure the distinct amount of inverted x-scale values to try and decipher a pattern for the number of elements
    // needed to display in the clustered icon box.
    svg.selectAll('rect.item').attr('x', d => xScale(d)).classed('deleteIcon', d => { console.log('text d: ', Math.floor(xScale(d))); });
    console.log(`Elements on chart: ${svg.selectAll('rect.item').size()}`);
}

renderEvents(changedDates);
```

```css
.svg-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 20px;
}

.svg-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>D3 Timescale Intro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="timescale" class="svg-container"></div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./timescale.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a D3v5 based on [Pan & Zoom Axes](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/db6b4335bf1662b413e7968910104f0f)

It gives the dates a fixed y-coord during parsing.
It calculates the month groups of the dates. After grouping the key of the group is the Time-in-milliseconds so we have to convert it first to a date when used: `new Date().setTime(parseInt(d.key))`

Based on the separation of the months on the X-axis it decides to draw the individual points (blue) or the group points (red).

You have to tweak the styling of the text and its alignment. And the group points are not clipped for some reason.

Every zoom/pan action all is redrawn based on a new `xScale`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.axis line {
  stroke-opacity: 0.3;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.view {
  fill: none;
  stroke:none;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

</style>
<button>Reset</button>
<div id="timescale" class="svg-container"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>

//D3 Timescale demo

const width = 1200,
    height = 500,
    parsedDate = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d");

const changedDates = [
    '1988-01-01', '1988-01-02', '1988-01-03',
    '1988-01-04', '1988-01-05', '1988-01-06',
    '1988-01-07', '1989-01-08', '1989-01-09',
    '1995-01-10', '1995-01-11', '1998-01-12',
    '1998-01-13', '1998-01-14', '2002-01-15',
    '2002-01-16', '2002-01-17', '2004-01-18',
    '2004-01-19', '2004-01-20', '2004-01-21',
    '2004-01-22', '2007-01-23', '2007-01-24',
    '2007-01-25', '2007-01-26', '2007-01-27',
    '2008-01-28', '2008-01-29', '2008-01-30',
    '2008-01-31', '2008-02-01', '2010-02-02',
    '2010-02-03', '2010-02-04', '2012-02-05',
    '2012-02-06', '2012-02-07', '2012-02-08',
    '2014-02-09', '2014-02-10', '2014-02-11',
    '2017-02-12', '2017-02-13', '2017-02-14',
    '2018-02-15', '2018-02-16', '2018-02-17',
    '2018-02-18', '2018-02-19', '2018-02-20'
].map(d => { return { date: parsedDate(d), y: Math.random() * 100 + 50 }; });

const svg = d3.select('#timescale')
        .append('svg')
            .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
            .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
            .classed('svg-content', true);
        // .attr('width', width)
        // .attr('height', height);

const clipPath = svg.append('defs')
    .append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'clip')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', width - 110)
    .attr('height', height);

var minDate = d3.min(changedDates, d => d.date);
var maxDate = d3.max(changedDates, d => d.date);
minDate.setUTCFullYear(minDate.getUTCFullYear()-1);
maxDate.setUTCFullYear(maxDate.getUTCFullYear()+1);

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([minDate, maxDate])
    .range([10, width - 110]);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([200, 0])
    .range([0, height - 29]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickSize(1);

const yAxis = d3.axisRight()
    .scale(yScale)
    .tickSize(1)
    .tickValues([0, 100, 200]);

var view = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "view")
    .attr("x", 0.5)
    .attr("y", 0.5)
    .attr("width", width - 109)
    .attr("height", height - 28);

var gX = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'xaxis')
    .attr('transform', `translate(10,${height-20})`)
    .call(xAxis);
    // .selectAll('text')
    // .style('font-size', '10px');

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'yaxis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 1100 + ',' + 10 + ')')
    .call(yAxis);
    // .selectAll('text')
    // .style('font-size', '10px');

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 100])
//    .translateExtent([[-100, -100], [width + 90, height + 100]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

d3.select("button")
    .on("click", resetted);

svg.call(zoom);

var points = svg.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'points');

var monthCount = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return Date.UTC(d.date.getUTCFullYear(), d.date.getUTCMonth(), 1); })
    .rollup(function(v) { return { count: v.length, y: Math.random() * 100 + 50 }; })
    .entries(changedDates);

function drawDates(dates, xScale) {
  var points = svg.select(".points");
  points.selectAll(".item").remove();
  // use domain to group the dates
  var minDate = xScale.domain()[0];
  var minDatep1m = new Date(minDate.getTime()+30*24*60*60*1000); // + 1 month
  var deltaX = xScale(minDatep1m) - xScale(minDate);
  if (deltaX > 20) {
    points.selectAll('.item')
      .data(dates)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'item')
      .attr('x', d => xScale(d.date))
      .attr('y', d => d.y)
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
      .style('fill', 'blue');
  } else {
    var groups = points.selectAll('.item')
      .data(monthCount)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'item')
      .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xScale(new Date().setTime(parseInt(d.key)))},${d.value.y})`);
    groups.append('rect')
      .attr('x', -5)
      .attr('y', -5)
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
      .style('fill', 'red');
    groups.append('text')
      .text(d => d.value.count);
  }
}

drawDates(changedDates, xScale);

function zoomed() {
  var transformedX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(transformedX));
  drawDates(changedDates, transformedX)
}

function resetted() {
  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, however some of the challenges that I'm facing is trying to find equivalents from your code to my code which is using the d3 v3.5 library. For example, you're setting your zoomed scale using this:

function zoomed() {
  var transformedX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(transformedX));
  drawDates(changedDates, transformedX)
}

How would I convert this to using d3 v3.5 as I'm trying to find the d3 v3.5 equivalent of transform.rescaleX for example?

Comment: The logic is right and I'm trying to implement a version of this using d3 v3.5. Can you please send an example using version 3.5 as a lot of things have changed in version 5, but I can't upgrade due to backward compatibility reasons of my other charts. Thanks again very much.

Comment: Search a zoom example that uses d3v3. And look at the code that draws a new axis. Porting of a v3 code to v5 only takes a few minutes and all of v3 can be done in v5, so there is no reason to stick to v3. Except the colorCategory20, but you can find the equivalents in v4 and copy these color arrays to your code. I don't write v3 code, I port all I need to v5.

Comment: Thanks, I was on the right track, however I needed to call my render method in my update function with the same xScale since D3 v3.5 doesn't have a rescale function. It's working now, thanks again for your help!